# How to reduce a Pages file's size?

Tags: pages, file

Having been using Pages for more than 3 years but there is one thing that puzzles me so much. And it can be a problem since I have written so many Pages files, that is the Pages' file size.

It is way too big, much much bigger than say a Word format .doc file.

The same two-page pure text document, if saved as a Pages document, has a size of 667 KB, but only 13 K as a Word document.

Do you have the same problem? Any suggestion on how to reduce the file size? Otherwise, I will run out of hard disk space very soon.

Answer (score 2):

When a Pages document includes images or video, the File->Reduce File Size menu at the top of Pages can sometimes help reduce the document's size. See the "[Reduce a document’s file size in Pages on Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-bh/guide/pages/tan0a3e805bf/mac)" Apple Support webpage for more details.

In general, however, a Pages document tends to be significantly larger than a Word file with similar content. The reason is that a Pages document is rather a "folder" with multiple files in it with metadata, a number of preview images and more. There is no way to permanently change that unless you save the Pages document in another format such as PDF, Word, Plain Text, etc.

To see that yourself, make a copy of a Pages file with a name different than the original (need not be a complex or large file at all). Then, rename the copy's extension  as `zip` and double-click on that zip file. This will create a new folder with the same name as the copy. Double-click on that folder and you will see a number of folders and files in it similar to that in the screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: A folder, or a zip file? Open Document Format (and docx) files are zip files, but OS X has a tradition of using _actual folders_ for things. Which is it here?

Comment: It used to be a folder many years ago, now it's a compressed folder (zip).

Comment: So sad. Pages is a very good program, especially working with tables and images. But I have to change to LibreOffice since the .pages file size is too big.